# Core ubuntu applications will not open

Tags: 14.04, command-line, nautilus

The Files and Terminal apps on my machine will not open.  Anytime I try, it loads for a bit, and then nothing.  No loading sign, no window, no gui, no error, nothing.  If it helps, when I start up my machine it shows an error saying that there was an issue with system applications.  I always click "report problem".

Comment: Click on "Show Details". Wait. Wait some more. Read the details.

Comment: 14.04 is going EOL this month, so you should upgrade. Not sure if that'll fix the problem, just mentioning.

Comment: I meant 18.04, but a reinstall worked.